# Book: woman woke from a coma on another planet, in a museum, escapes with a baby boy

Tags: story-identification, books

About 10 years ago I read a book about a woman who woke from a coma to find herself as a museum exhibit on another planet.

There were lots of other creatures in the room including a baby boy. She took the baby and escaped. She traveled with the baby for months, having various adventures and meeting lots of different life forms who helped her. It finally turned out that the baby was a stolen prince. He had a twin sister.

It was a novel in English. Unfortunately I have no memory of the cover.

Comment: Can you [edit] this to add more information in? For example, how long ago was many years? Was it new or old then? Do you know what the cover looked like? What format was it: novel, short story, etc?

Comment: Hi there! :) there's already good info in there, but maybe you could take a look at [this guide on how to ask a good story-ID question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/98028), see if that triggers any more memories you could [edit] in? For instance, when is "many years ago"? 60s? 80s? Two years ago? Did you read that in English, was it a translation? Do you remember what the cover looked like? Stuff like that, to increase the chances of a successful ID. Cheers!

Comment: While your comment was kind (and certainly appreciated by the users) we try to keep our posts clean and strictly about the content, as such I've removed it. (It's also our pleasure, as community reviewers/moderators-sans-power, to improve the quality of posts on this site and ensure users get the answers they're looking for)